# Array in object can't access typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a Mean APP. I have a service that give me an object from mongoDB:
The console show:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhR59.jpg)

This is the code:

> Blockquote

```
export class AllocatViewComponent implements OnInit {

equipment;


constructor(
private location: Location,
private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
private router: Router,
private equipmentService: EquipmentService,
) { }


 @ViewChild('myModal')
 modal: BsModalComponent;

 @ViewChild('deleteModal')
 modal2: BsModalComponent;

 ngOnInit() {

 this.equipmentService.getOneById(this.currentUrl.id).subscribe(data => {
  // Check if GET request was success or not
  if (!data.success) {
    this.messageClass = 'alert alert-danger'; // Set bootstrap error class
    this.message = data.message; // Set error message
  } else {
    this.equipment =data.equipment;
    console.log(this.equipment) // log that i share
  }
   });
  }

  save(form){

   var port = {
   numberPort: this.portToEdit.numberPort,
   connector: "",
   speedCircuit: "",
   status: "Available",
   function: "",
   serviceType: "",
   network: "",
   connectedTo: "",
   customerName: "",
   addressCustomer: "",
   lelisID: form.controls.lelisID.value,
   requester: "",
   dateRequester: Date,
   carrier: ""
 }


this.modal.close();
 }


 }
```

How I can access to this.equipment.cards["x"].ports["y"].status 
I tried but: [ts] Property 'cards' does not exist on type '{}'

Thank you!

Comment: you should be able to access it with just `this.equiment["property"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have declared a plain object, your compiler is not able to recognize the properties that are set to `this.equipment`. Try doing `this.equipment["cards"]["x"].ports["y"].status`.